# wamp osCommerce ebay module trouble with function eregi

Tags: php, wamp, ebay-api, oscommerce

I am currently trying to get the eBay auction module for OS commerce but found out that the eregi function is deprecated.  I searched in several posts but the solutions weren't useful.  I don't really know much php but due to the nature of the assignment, I'm forced to carry on with it.

The code I'm apparently having trouble with is:

```
        $URL = 'http://cgi6.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewListedItems&userid=' . EBAY_USERID . '&include=0&since=' . AUCTION_ENDED . '&sort=' . AUCTION_SORT . '&rows=0'; 

// Where to Start grabbing and where to End grabbing
$GrabStart = '<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">';
$GrabEnd = 'About eBay';

// Open the file
$file = fopen("$URL", "r");

// Read the file

if (!function_exists('file_get_contents')) {
     $r = fread($file, 80000);
} 
else {
    $r = file_get_contents($URL);  
}


// Grab just the contents we want
$stuff = eregi("$GrabStart(.*)$GrabEnd", $r, $content);
```

---- end of code

I had a similar issue with split but changing it to explode solved the issue now with eregi it doesn't quite work with preg match or I'm not usign it properly.

Thanks for your attention

Kind Regards

Juan Fernando Baird

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I am no great shakes with regex's so I tried to test your existing eregi using php 5.2.9 and 5.2.6 to see what it returned. It always returned FALSE in $stuff and $contents was not set to anything. So its just possible this code never actually did anything!!

So this is a little dangerous as I cannot be exactly sure what the code was actually trying to return i.e. did it want the $GrabStart and or $GrabEnd to appear in the result or not.

This will probably do the job. And probably use a lot less resource as it wont have to load the regex engine for a fairly simple text manipulation.

```
$r = 'aaa<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">xxxAbout eBaybbb';
$conent = '';

$GrabStart = '<tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">';
$GrabEnd = 'About eBay';

/*
 *  This will return the GrabStart and GrabEnd data in the result
    p1 3
    p2 40
    $content = <tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">xxxAbout eBay
*/
$p1 = strpos($r, $GrabStart);
$p2 = strpos($r, $GrabEnd) + strlen($GrabEnd);
$content = substr($r, $p1, $p2-$p1);

echo 'p1 ' . $p1 . PHP_EOL;
echo 'p2 ' . $p2 . PHP_EOL;
echo $content . PHP_EOL;

/*
*  This will just return the data between GrabStart and GrabEnd and not the start and end sentinals
    p1 27
    p2 30
    $content = xxx
*/
$p1 = strpos($r, $GrabStart) + strlen($GrabStart);
$p2 = strpos($r, $GrabEnd, $p1);
$content = substr($r, $p1, $p2-$p1);

echo 'p1 ' . $p1 . PHP_EOL;
echo 'p2 ' . $p2 . PHP_EOL;
echo $content . PHP_EOL;
```

I hope this is of some help although it may beg as many questions as it attempts to answer.

Comment: hmmm shoul i replace juts the code  posted? or it need more adaptation?, as i said im not quite familiar of php so kinda need to know if it needs something else hehe, sorry if that bothers you but  let me know if i need to adapt it, what to adapt and if not. great :D

Comment: just tried it out, the simpler way i could think of and it didnt work, i just comented the eregi line and pasted your code. i know it might be dumb but really ive never used php in my life so im kinda lost in here